# ML.NET C# How do I get a list of predicted employee groups output?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, prediction, ml.net

is there a way to output grouped items using the prediction algorithm and clustering?
here is an example i have a list of 50 employees and i want to put them into groups of 10 by predicting which employees best suited to work together in a group and then output those 5 groups with 10 employees each.

the elements that will be used to make the prediction will be (

experience from 1 - 10 years experience,
easy to work with rated by yes or no options
Visual learner vs non visual learner
and if the employee is a quick learner or not
thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is there text missing after the "("?

Answer (score 0):

Output is easy.

Just print the identifiers.

However, I doubt that you will be able to just compute the partitions you explained. Certainly not with clustering: it will put *similar* objects together, not produce groups of 10 each that "get together well" (however an affirm would be able to identify this). Do you still have a group with the 3 skilled seniors, one with 10 skilled juniors, and one with 36 incompetent unskilled with no experience, and one containing only the pointy haired boss (senior but unskilled) etc.

So the difficulty is not the output.